# Does simple rescaling from 1080p to frame height of 720 lead to 720p?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert a 1080p to 720p and also lower resolutions eventually.

I have been using `ffmpeg` for all my video processing activities so far, and would simply approach this task using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i tos.mov -vf scale=-1:720 tos_0x720.mov`

I understand that this will rescale my video to a new frame size having 720 pixels set as a fixed height and the width dynamically calculated.

What I am not sure about are the implications regarding the quality factors of the video when using `ffmpeg` this way.

1. Is it valid to assume that running this command will output a perfect HD 720p quality video?
2. What would be a benefit of using dedicated video conversion software to accomplish my goal compared to running the above command?

Comment: It is discouraged to crosspost [the same question](http://superuser.com/questions/955841/does-simple-rescaling-from-1080p-to-frame-height-of-720-lead-to-720p) on multiple [se] sites.

Comment: Yeah sorry and thanks for the hint, I wasn't sure where to post it... But I guess it's more appropriate to post it only at _Superuser_ since it's not _really_ a programming question... I just wan't sure because I never used _Superuser_ before and was uncertain about the feedback I would get there (which was actually really great in the end). Problem is I can't delete it here any more since it's already answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You can choose which [scaling algorithm](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-scaler.html) to use by setting the `flags` option in the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale). Some algorithms work better for up-scaling (`bilinear`) while others are better for down-sampling (`bicubic`, `lanczos`). Some are better for sharp graphics, others for gradual changes, some are faster and some are slower.

   I think the default value for `flags` downsampling is `bicubic`, while some people [recommend `lanczos`](https://superuser.com/questions/375718/which-resize-algorithm-to-choose-for-videos).

   To set the flag use:

   `-vf scale=-1:720:flags=lanczos`
2. Commercial video conversion software use the same algorithms. For eg. Adobe Premiere used variable-radius bicubic for Maximum Render Quality. They might help you choose one ore another depending on what you're after (speed vs. quality) and they [may provide tweaks](http://pixinsight.com/doc/docs/InterpolationAlgorithms/InterpolationAlgorithms.html#__section002__) to reduce artifacts resulting from scaling.

There's a lot of literature covering the different algorithms.